# How to start a process with low integrity level

Tags: process, internet-explorer-8, low-level, protected-mode

I have a socket client running as BHO object which tries to communicate with Desktop application. As the IE is running in low integrity level the bho is not loaded with IE running under protected mode. I have two questions.

1. How to start process with low-integrity level.
2. Will it help with BHO object loading even under protected mode.

Answer (score 1):

This article provides sample code on how to do it.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2278183

A protected mode/low integrity instance of IE can load BHOs. Perhaps you might either need to have your plugin/DLL signed (by a vendor thru a trusted CA) or modify your IE security settings to allow unsigned plugins.